# Puppeteersharp C#, trying to click on a span and get error at span.ClickAsync(): "ErrorNode is either not visible or not an HTMLElement"

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

IM using Puppeteersharp C#, I got this error at span.ClickAsync():
"ErrorNode is either not visible or not an HTMLElement"

any idea how to fix it?

```
 var span = await page.WaitForSelectorAsync("#gallery > div.footer > div > div > div:nth-child(3) > span.nav-next");
 await span.ClickAsync();
```

here the html:

```
<div class="nav">
<span class="nav-prev" style="user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); touch-action: none; display: none;"></span>
<span class="nav-next" style="user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); touch-action: none;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the element visible, can you click on it manually?

Comment: My bad, after putting Headless = false, I wa able to see that the element wasn't visible!